# No module named 'config' while uploading image on gcloud -django

Tags: python, django, gcloud, image-upload

I am trying to upload an image to  gcloud server through admin area but it shows 
error

```
  No module named 'config'
```

I am using gcloud proxy to use gcloud database

here is the error trail-

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "F:\duit\duit_backend_env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
    File "F:\duit\duit_backend_env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
     File "F:\duit\duit_backend_env\lib\site- 
     packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
    **callback_kwargs)
    File "F:\duit\duit_backend_env\lib\site-
    packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
    File "F:\duit\duit_backend_env\lib\site- 
     packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
    File "F:\duit\duit_backend_env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, i 
    n import_module
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _ 
      find_and_load_unlocked
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _ 
      call_with_frames_removed
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in 
     _find_and_load_unlocked 
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

edit -
the remaining middle of error trail
[image]

**edit 2-**

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.storage_backends.GoogleCloudMediaStorage'
#STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'config.storage_backends.GoogleCloudStaticStorage'
GS_PROJECT_ID = 'myid'
GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
#GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
#STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME)
MEDIA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME)
```

Comment: you've removed part of the error trace (...) which points to where the failing `import` statement is.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't allowing me to add a complete trail...it says "looks like most of it is code. please add some details"

Comment: Then post the relevant part of the error that actually shows the cause of the error.

Comment: @dirkgroten check the snapshot I just attached....this is the complete middle part that I omitted at the first place

Comment: Show us your settings.py (DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE), the part relevant to gcloud settings.

Comment: DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.storage_backends.GoogleCloudMediaStorage'
#STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'config.storage_backends.GoogleCloudStaticStorage'
GS_PROJECT_ID = 'myid'
GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
#GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
#STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME)
MEDIA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME)

Comment: Please don't paste code in the comments. Add it to your question by editing your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197952/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-kartik-gautam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setting `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.storage_backends.GoogleCloudMediaStorage'` is wrong. I have no idea where you get that from.

If you read the instructions for setting up Google Cloud storage in the [docs of django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) you would see that the correct setting is:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
```